# Kohana Formo Error: Invalid method formo called in Model_User

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

Trying to use the Formo module with ORM and Kohana 3.1, but keep getting this error...

```
Invalid method formo called in Model_User
```

I get this error with any Model I try to use. The user model is the default one that comes with ORM. The code I try is as follows.

```
    $user = ORM::factory('user', 1);

    $form = Formo::form()
        ->orm('load', $user);
```

The Formo module is the newest one I could get from GitHub... v2.0RC2-24

I can't seem to figure out what it is that I could be doing wrong... thanks...

Comment: Its probably looking for a specific method in your `Model_User` class that needs to be built to enable the Formo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datasage you are correct, if you wish to "answer" the question I'll gladly hand over the answer to you. All I needed was to declare the formo() method in my models.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

    // FOR FORMO
    public function formo()
    {

    }

} // End User Model
```